# Vue 3 pass event handler to setup component function

Tags: event-handling, vuejs3

I would like to pass an event handler to the `setup` function of a component.

Just like I can do it with the `h` function, working example below:

```
const vNode = h(Component, {
  onEventName: (event) => {
    console.log(event)
  }
}
```

I would like to do it using the `setup` function, like:

```
const setupResult = Component.setup({
  onEventName: (event) => {
    console.log(event)
  }
})
```

But it seems like not working. Any ideas, please?